# Nodejs server sometimes fails to upload files using multer, express, forever

Tags: node.js, express, forever, multer

I am trying to build a simple file server to receive files from post request with multipart/form-data and I followed the multer tutorial but it seems something is not quite right and it sometimes returns 500 internal server error. The code is in the following.

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var app = express();
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    var dir = 'file/' + req.body.jobid + '/';
    mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
    cb(null, dir);
    console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/', upload.single("file"),function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).end();
  next(req,res);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The error happens like every two requests out of ten.

The code I used to start forever

```
forever start app.js;
```

I am new to nodejs and this kind of errors (errors that happen occasionally) is killing me.

I added some functions to log the possible errors.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: err.stack });
  } else {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

and it logged something like this:

```
Upload: saved to file/9974de5b-a9c7-4de2-92d0-5dcf277b3946/file123
Error: ENOENT, open 'file/9974de5b-a9c7-4de2-92d0-5dcf277b3946/file123'
    at Error (native)
Error: ENOENT, open 'file/9974de5b-a9c7-4de2-92d0-5dcf277b3946/file123'
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is likely happening, is that sometimes your code is throwing a synchronous error, which express by default will turn into a 500 response. It's pretty difficult to diagnose without knowing what the error is. What you should do is add an error handler before `var server`, which will catch errors and log them to console. Then when the error occurs, you'll easily be able to see it and fix the issue.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

EDIT

Move the line `cb(null, dir);` up a line, as such:

```
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    var dir = 'file/' + req.body.jobid + '/';
    mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        // move cb to here
        cb(null, dir);
    });

    console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be working. It keeps printing out all the req. I also have a question about the "next(err);". Why are you passing the err to the next function in the stack? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you copy it in your code exactly as is? In order for it to work, the function NEEDS to have exactly 4 parameters (err, req, res, next) even if they are not used by the function. Many people get this wrong because they use ESlint which complains about unused variables. It should only print out error objects. If its printing out every request, then there's definitely something wrong.

Comment: The reason I call next(err) is because I don't know how you want to handle the connection at this point, and all I really care about is logging it. So I pass the `err` along so that Express can handle it, and correctly close the connection.

Comment: I used the express tutorial code to catch the log the error and it shows something like this.
Upload: saved to file/9974de5b-a9c7-4de2-92d0-5dcf277b3946/file123
Error: ENOENT, open 'file/9974de5b-a9c7-4de2-92d0-5dcf277b3946/file123'
    at Error (native)
I think I should include it in my question.

Comment: The problem seems to be gone. so the problem is the cb() was called before the mkdirp() had finished? Thank you so much.

Comment: Can I ask two more questions? I found that the cb() is actually not passed into the callback function of mkdirp(). Why am I able to call cb() in the callback function of mkdrip()? If I also put my console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname) into the callback function, will it fail?

Comment: Moving the console.log won't affect anything, that's fine. You need to call `cb(null,dir)` in the callbak function of mkdrip because you only want to being the file saving AFTER the directory has been created, hence you have to wait for mkdir to complete before triggering the callback with the directory name.